# Access Control List per row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, acl

I have a tasks table on the cloud and I want users to be able share their tasks with others. I need to be able to tell which users can read each given row.

- Do I need to create a 1 to many table to specify which users have
  access to a given row? Or can I just create a varchar column with json type data
  specifying the users ?
- And if the json column is viable, would there be a great performance penalty ?
- How can I query such table ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically comes down to indexing. Can you index the access control entries in the access control list for efficient querying?

If your table looks like this:

```
create table task (
  id int primary key,
  subject varchar(255) not null,
  owner varchar(255) not null references some_user_table(name), --owner can has full permission on own record
  acl varchar(max) null
);
```

And an ACL could look like this:

```
[ {grantee:"public", read:true, write:false, grantor:"reverend"} ]
```

How do you index such values? In Posgres, you can index JSON entire fields or individual JSON array entries, but not all array entries. I'm not too familiar with XML indexing in SQL Server, but [it exists](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx).

If your schema looks like this:

```
create table task (
  task_id int primary key,
  subject varchar(255) not null,
  owner varchar(255) not null --references some user table
);

create table task_acl (
  task_id int references task(task_id) on delete cascade,
  grantee varchar(255) not null, --the role getting the privilege
  privilege char(1) not null check (privilege in ('r', 'w', 't') ), --r=read, w=write, t=take ownership
  admin_option boolean not null default false, --whether grantee can grant privileges to others for this task
  grantor varchar(255) not null default current_user, --the role granting the privilege

  primary key (id, grantee, privilege)
);
```

Then at least you can index the grantee and privilege fields.

You would query this with a `WHERE EXISTS` clause to see if current user is in the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside data layers using views.